# concatenate with jquery

Tags: jquery, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate a string in a div with jQuery. Here is my code:

```
var server = 'server name: '
$('#div').load('myservername.aspx');
```

I'd like to display:

server name: myserver

How can I best achieve this?

Comment: user79127, if Ryu's answer was the one that solved it for you, check it as the correct answer (by clicking the green checkmark).

Answer (score 13):

Tweaking what you have

```
$('#div').load('myservername.aspx');
$('#div').prepend('Server Name:')
```

Could also do

```
$.get("myservername.aspx", function(data){

$('#div').html('Server name: ' + data)

});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [manipulation docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append#content) have these little codes to append

```
$("p").append("<strong>Hello</strong>");
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming that you have an html with the following html code

```
<div id="some_id">
</div>
```

and you want to load the div with server name: myserver (?).

If so, i think you can use

```
$('#some_id').text("server name: myserver");
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point that `myservername.aspx` seems to return the name of a server. Hard coding it to 'myserver' is easy, but not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: to clarify I like to concatenate
var server = 'server name: '
$('#div').load('myservername.aspx');

server + ' ' + $('#div').load('myservername.aspx');

Comment: I see what you mean.  Yeah I can do that, but I like to have it dynamic change. :-)